# R - sample within paired data

Tags: r, dplyr, sample

I am trying to randomly sample a variable within paired data. 
`idmen` is my pair-couple **identifier**, `idind` is my perso **identifier** and `jour` is the variable that needs to be randomly subset. `jour` needs to be same for one `idmen` pair. So for example, `idmen == 2`, we need to subset etheir `dimanche` or `vendredi`.

This is the data

```
    idmen idind  jour actpr1
      1     1 lundi       111
      1     2 lundi       111
      2     1 dimanche    111
      2     2 dimanche    111
      2     1 vendredi    111
      2     2 vendredi    111
      3     1 dimanche    113
      3     2 dimanche    121
      3     1 lundi       111
      3     2 lundi       111
```

This is the desired output 
(of course the ouput can varies because it must be randomly selected)

I need to sample one day for each `idmen`.

```
     idmen idind  jour actpr1
      1     1 lundi       111
      1     2 lundi       111
      2     1 dimanche    111
      2     2 dimanche    111
      3     1 dimanche    113
      3     2 dimanche    121
```

I thought of something like

```
library(dplyr) 
dta %>% group_by(idmen, jour) %>% sample_n(2)
```

But I do not understand why this is not working.

Any clue ?

```
structure(list(idmen = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), idind = c(1, 
 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2), jour = structure(c(3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
 7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("dimanche", "jeudi   ", "lundi   ", 
 "mardi   ", "mercredi", "samedi  ", "vendredi"), class = "factor"), 
actpr1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("111", "112", "113", "121", "122", "123", 
"131", "132", "141", "143", "144", "145", "146", "151", "211", 
"212", "213", "223", "231", "233", "241", "261", "262", "271", 
"272", "311", "312", "313", "324", "331", "332", "334", "335", 
"341", "342", "343", "351", "372", "373", "374", "381", "382", 
"384", "385", "399", "411", "412", "413", "414", "419", "422", 
"423", "429", "431", "433", "510", "511", "512", "513", "514", 
"521", "522", "523", "524", "531", "532", "533", "541", "542", 
"613", "614", "616", "621", "622", "623", "627", "631", "632", 
"633", "634", "635", "636", "637", "638", "641", "651", "653", 
"655", "658", "661", "662", "663", "665", "667", "668", "669", 
"671", "672", "673", "674", "678", "810", "811", "812", "813", 
"819", "911", "999"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("idmen", 
 "idind", "jour", "actpr1"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
> dta %>% group_by(idmen) %>% filter(jour == jour[sample(length(jour),1)])
Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
Groups: idmen [3]

  idmen idind     jour actpr1
  (dbl) (dbl)   (fctr) (fctr)
1     1     1 lundi       111
2     1     2 lundi       111
3     2     1 vendredi    111
4     2     2 vendredi    111
5     3     1 lundi       111
6     3     2 lundi       111
```

...although it would be kind of neat to have a "sample complete groups" function built into **dplyr** perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Base R solution:

```
dta[unlist(sample(as.data.frame(matrix(1:nrow(dta),nrow = 2)),10,replace=T)),]
```

This takes advantage of the fact that a dataframe is a list.  When you use `sample()` on a list it will take an entire column of a dataframe.  Then just use `unlist()` on the result and you have sampled two rows together.  This samples 10 pairs with replacement, but that can be changed of course.